# T-SQL - Update rows with calculated values from previous rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

I need to create a dataset that calculates values using results from the previous row, but only the first row contains an actual value.

This is my dataset:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    Date DATE
    , Month INT
    , Increment FLOAT
    , Results FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO #tmp(Date, Month, Increment, Results) 
VALUES
('7/1/2022', 0, 0.0027347877960046, 0.00439631056653702)
, ('7/1/2022', 1,   0.0332610867687839, NULL)
, ('7/1/2022', 2,   0.0541567096339919, NULL)
, ('7/1/2022', 3,   0.0534245249728661, NULL)
, ('7/1/2022', 4,   0.0497604938051764, NULL)
, ('7/1/2022', 5,   0.0448266874224477, NULL)
, ('7/1/2022', 6,   0.0637221774467554, NULL)
, ('7/1/2022', 7,   0.0953341922962425, NULL)
, ('7/1/2022', 8,   0.117940928214655,  NULL)
, ('7/1/2022', 9,   0.0955895317176205, NULL)
, ('6/1/2022',  0,  0.0027347877960046, 0.00439631056653702)
, ('6/1/2022',  1,  0.0332610867687839, 0.00752724387918406)
, ('6/1/2022',  2,  0.0541567096339919, NULL)
, ('6/1/2022',  3,  0.0534245249728661, NULL)
, ('6/1/2022',  4,  0.0497604938051764, NULL)
, ('6/1/2022',  5,  0.0448266874224477, NULL)
, ('6/1/2022',  6,  0.0637221774467554, NULL)
, ('6/1/2022',  7,  0.0953341922962425, NULL)
, ('6/1/2022',  8,  0.117940928214655,  NULL)
, ('6/1/2022',  9,  0.0955895317176205, NULL)
```

I need the Results = Previous Results + Increment

```
Date    Month   Increment   Results
6/1/2022    0   0.002734788 0.004396311
6/1/2022    1   0.033261087 0.007527244
6/1/2022    2   0.05415671  0.061683954
6/1/2022    3   0.053424525 0.115108478
6/1/2022    4   0.049760494 0.164868972
6/1/2022    5   0.044826687 0.20969566
6/1/2022    6   0.063722177 0.273417837
6/1/2022    7   0.095334192 0.368752029
6/1/2022    8   0.117940928 0.486692958
6/1/2022    9   0.095589532 0.582282489
7/1/2022    0   0.002734788 0.004396311
7/1/2022    1   0.033261087 0.037657397
7/1/2022    2   0.05415671  0.091814107
7/1/2022    3   0.053424525 0.145238632
7/1/2022    4   0.049760494 0.194999126
7/1/2022    5   0.044826687 0.239825813
7/1/2022    6   0.063722177 0.303547991
7/1/2022    7   0.095334192 0.398882183
7/1/2022    8   0.117940928 0.516823111
7/1/2022    9   0.095589532 0.612412643
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using @larnu's row between method.  Needed to split the data in two tables and union them together.  Table one contains the actual Results column and table 2 contains the incrementally calculated Results.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp;
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    Date DATE
    , Month INT
    , Increment FLOAT
    , Results FLOAT
)
;
INSERT INTO #tmp(Date, Month, Increment, Results) 
VALUES
('7/1/2022', 0, 0.0027347877960046, 0.00439631056653702)
, ('7/1/2022', 1,   0.0332610867687839, NULL)
, ('7/1/2022', 2,   0.0541567096339919, NULL)
, ('7/1/2022', 3,   0.0534245249728661, NULL)
, ('7/1/2022', 4,   0.0497604938051764, NULL)
, ('7/1/2022', 5,   0.0448266874224477, NULL)
, ('7/1/2022', 6,   0.0637221774467554, NULL)
, ('7/1/2022', 7,   0.0953341922962425, NULL)
, ('7/1/2022', 8,   0.117940928214655,  NULL)
, ('7/1/2022', 9,   0.0955895317176205, NULL)
, ('6/1/2022',  0,  0.0027347877960046, 0.00439631056653702)
, ('6/1/2022',  1,  0.0332610867687839, 0.00752724387918406)
, ('6/1/2022',  2,  0.0541567096339919, NULL)
, ('6/1/2022',  3,  0.0534245249728661, NULL)
, ('6/1/2022',  4,  0.0497604938051764, NULL)
, ('6/1/2022',  5,  0.0448266874224477, NULL)
, ('6/1/2022',  6,  0.0637221774467554, NULL)
, ('6/1/2022',  7,  0.0953341922962425, NULL)
, ('6/1/2022',  8,  0.117940928214655,  NULL)
, ('6/1/2022',  9,  0.0955895317176205, NULL)
;

WITH mt AS (
    SELECT
        Date
        , MAX(Month) AS Month
    FROM #tmp
    WHERE Results IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Date
),
results AS (
    SELECT 
        t.*

        , SUM(CASE WHEN t.Results IS NOT NULL THEN t.Results END) OVER(PARTITION BY t.Date) +
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.Results IS NULL THEN t.Increment END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Date ORDER BY t.Date, t.Month ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Results2
    FROM #tmp t
    INNER JOIN mt mt ON t.Date = mt.Date AND t.Month >= mt.Month
)
SELECT
    t.Date 
    , t.Month 
    , t.Increment 
    , t.Results
FROM #tmp t
LEFT JOIN mt mt ON t.Date = mt.Date 
WHERE t.Month <= mt.Month

UNION ALL

SELECT
    r.Date 
    , r.Month 
    , r.Increment
    , r.Results2 AS Results
FROM results r
WHERE r.results2 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Date, Month
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could use a cumulative `SUM` here. As, however, you need to use the `Results` from `Month` `0` and *ignore* the value of `Increment` for `Month` `0`, you also need to use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT *,
       SUM(CASE MONTH WHEN 0 THEN Results END) OVER () +
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month > 0 THEN Increment END) OVER (ORDER BY Month ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Results2
FROM #tmp;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=9caeadb9edc2315ce5a8d29ac1a42fb3)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This looks to work for this situation.  But my actual dataset is a little more complex.  I just edited my example above, which doesn't work with this solution.  My dataset has many "dates" and the result sets are null in different "months".

Comment: Add a `PARTITION BY`, @RobOng ?

Comment: I don't think I'm adding this right.

I changed the line to:


, SUM(CASE WHEN Results IS NOT NULL THEN results END) OVER() +
  SUM(CASE WHEN Results IS NULL THEN Increment END) OVER (PARTITION BY Date, Month ORDER BY Date, Month ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Results2


But the results are not accurate.

Comment: Why are you partitioning by `Month` as well?

Comment: My mistake.  Removing month from the partition has corrected the calculation for date 7/1/2022, but 6/1/2022 is still not calculating properly.  It's including month 0 in the calculation when it should only include the row with the last value in results.  Is there something else I need to add to OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Date, Month ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)?